# How to use Discord uid to authenticate a Kerberos user?

Tags: kerberos

I'm doing a project to control a club room (light, door-lock, ...) using a web-interface and a Discord bot.

I have set up a Samba-based ActiveDirectory to manage accounts and the LDAP will contain a `discordid` field to link Discord accounts.

I want the Discord bot to get a Kerberos TGT on the behalf of user using the Discord id as username and no password. Obviously only the Kerberos authenticated Discord bot can do that.

In other words,

1. I want to get a TGT for a user
2. With no password and the TGT requester being Kerberos authenticated
3. Using an integer as username (not a problem, I can easily get the real username linked to the integer)

Like a `sudo -u`, but at the Kerberos level (I won't `sudo -u` for real). This way, Kerberos aware services "just works" without knowing what is Discord.

I understand concepts of Kerberos but I'm a complete beginner (this was my first ActiveDirectory).

I see that the MIT Kerberos support plugins, I think it's mandatory for my purpose but I haven't found any good API documentation yet.

Do you have any hints or recommendations to achieve that ?

Comment: AFAIK: no, you can't do that, because the whole point of Kerberos is secure authentication of a "user" himself (or itself) thru an insecure network. You want local impersonation of a "user" -- don't use Kerberos. That would be like feeding meat-based carrots to a vegan.

Comment: The Hadoop project chose Kerberos for authentication across a distributed system (while Kerberos is designed for point-to-point auth -- another bad choice) and had to invent various band-aids to build a functional solution. Among these, the concept of **proxy user** >> a privileged Kerberos user that target services "trust" enough to launch local Linux processes under an arbitrary, impersonated Linux account. But that's completely outside of Kerberos itself _(Krb is only used to securely authentify the privileged user)_

Comment: I'm doing Kerberos impersonation, the `sudo -u` was a misleading image that I cleared.
I want to reuse existing authentication infrastructure for the Discord bot instead of creating another one, the bot is really a frontend for other services. It could send mails, print documents, ...

Comment: Again an inspiration from the Hadoop stack: build a catalog of all your users' passwords on the machine thatt runs your bot, i.e. a list of "keytab" files, and use them to get TGTs on behalf of your users. Highly insecure for end users though _(using keytabs for headless stuff.. i.e. scheduled jobs or services is mandatory since there is n other way)_

Comment: Usually a KDC will allow a privileged account to retrieve a keytab for another user... but wil require a password change (either as an arg, or randomly chosen) for that.